# Android tablet compatibility

Tags: android, resolution, tablet, dpi

I've got different dimen values/images for ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi which work fine on phones. But when a low res tablet is running my app it goes to the mdpi values. Which means a big tablet screen gets the lower dimen values (and images) and everything looks extra small.

I'm sure it can be solved pragmatically but is there a way to solve it using XML? I would really like to avoid solving this in real time, seems like an overkill and pointless.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting point from which tablets are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) in the Android docs.

You can use `drawable-large` and `drawable-xlarge` as needed along with `drawable-large-mdpi`, for example.